# How can I get a property of an object in powershell without using parentheses?

Tags: powershell

I often find that I have to surround a command in parentheses and then use the property access operator (dot-syntax) to get the value of a property. This is rather annoying since I have to go back to the beginning of the line when I'd rather just keep typing where I am. It is especially annoying when I am in the middle of a larger set of piped commands.

## Example

If I have the following command

```
Get-PSProvider FileSystem
```

and I want to get the `Drives` property, I would have to surround the whole command in parentheses first:

```
(Get-PSProvider FileSystem).Drives
```

Is there a faster way to get the value of a single property?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty <property name>`. This can be shortened using the alias `select` and only typing part of the property name:

```
Get-PSProvider FileSystem| select -exp Drives
```

An additional benefit to this method is that you can access a single property for multiple objects.

This will not return anything (**Update:** This does work in PowerShell v3.):

```
(Get-PSProvider).Drives
```

However, this will return the drives for all providers:

```
Get-PSProvider| select -exp Drives
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for the correction.